# Error in connecting R to Redshift

Tags: r, amazon-redshift, rjdbc

I'm trying to connect `RStudio` to `Amazon Redshift` via `JDBC` and this is what I tried to run:

```
driver <- JDBC("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver", "~/Downloads/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar", identifier.quote="`")
# url <- "<JDBCURL>:<PORT>/<DBNAME>?user=<USER>&password=<PW>
url <- "jdbc:redshift://<cluster-name>.<xxxxxx>.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/<dbname>?user=<username>&password=<password>"

conn <- dbConnect(driver, url)
```

When executing `dbConnect()`, I get the following error:

```
Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
  java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: Operation timed out.
```

Any idea what is causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Update: There was a problem with access through security groups. If you're having a similar issue, check the inbound rules of your security group and make sure they allow access to Redshift via your IP.